# React Native componentWillReceiveProps doesn't call right when I update Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, componentwillreceiveprops

Ok so this are my buttons where I **add** and **delete** from cart in *ProductScreen* :

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.addToCart()}}>
                   <Text>add to cart</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

   <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.updateCart({'numberOfProducts':0,'products':[]})}}>
                   <Text>Erase cart</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity>
```

The **addToCart function** :

```
addToCart = () =>{
    let currentCartProducts = this.props.cart;
    currentCartProducts.numberOfProducts++;
    this.setState({
        currentProductToAdd:Object.assign(
            this.state.currentProductToAdd,
                {
                    'toalPriceOfProductWithExtras': this.props.navigation.getParam('price') * this.state.value,
                    'piecesOfProduct': this.state.value,
                }
        )
    })
    currentCartProducts.products.push(this.state.currentProductToAdd);
    this.props.updateCart(currentCartProducts);
}
```

The **CartReducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {'numberOfProducts':0,'products':[]};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'update':
      return action.payload;
    default: 
     return state;
  }
};
```

The **CartAction**

```
export const updateCart = (val) => {
    return{
      type: 'update',
      payload: val
    };
  };
```

And the **CartScreen componentWillReceiveProps** where I want to render the products that are in cart. The redux works good , and I have all the data stored correctly but they don't render !

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('I m in componentWillReceiveProps')
    if (this.props.cart !== nextProps.cart) {
        console.log('OLD CART')
        console.log(this.props.cart)
        console.log('NEW CART')
        console.log(nextProps.cart)
    }
}
```

When I press add it doesn't work , but when I press delete it works !

**After one add and one delete :**

```
I m in componentWillReceiveProps
OLD CART
Object {
  "numberOfProducts": 1,
  "products": Array [
    Object {
      "extras": undefined,
      "piecesOfProduct": 1,
      "productName": "Chips",
      "productPrice": 0,
      "restaurantAddres": "Tay House 300 Bath St",
      "restaurantName": "time2dine - Spaces",
      "toalPriceOfProductWithExtras": 0,
    },
  ],
}
NEW CART
Object {
  "numberOfProducts": 0,
  "products": Array [],
}
```

**After another delete press:**

```
I m in componentWillReceiveProps
OLD CART
Object {
  "numberOfProducts": 0,
  "products": Array [],
}
NEW CART
Object {
  "numberOfProducts": 0,
  "products": Array [],
}
```

It's strange because at the second press on delete the cart props are the same... but when I add and the props change doesn't show anything.

*Thank you !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not properly updating your store.

```
case 'update':`
 return {...state, ...action.payload};
```

Update this in `cartReducer.js`. You should remember to use the spread operator otherwise the state will be the same anytime you update the store which will cause the `componentWillReceiveProps` not work as expected. Hope it helps!!.. **Happy Coding!!**

Comment: Thank you so much ! This was the problem !